# How can I make my fastcolored textbox transparent?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox

I'm trying to make a script executor for a game and the fast colored text box is white but I need it to be transparent but I cannot do that.

Comment: Regular TextBox is a legacy control that will not support this well..

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting
Then you have the option to change the background on the properties, or you can
Its called BackColor.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your answer?

Comment: I didn't really get his question, so I tried helping him the most, basically, I saw this fast colored textbox before, there is an option to change the BackColor.
When you click it the properties window should pop up on the side, you could change this overthere